# Discord.js Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I just started developing with Javascript and Discord.js a few days ago and got this Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined

I am trying to make a poll command. This is the Code (I deleted everything else and just wanted it to get the channel out of it):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Collection();

 module.exports = {
    name: 'poll',
    description: 'can make polls',
    cooldown: 5,
    usage: '[ask] [emoji1] [emoji 2]',
    aliases: ['createpoll'],
    execute(message, args) {
        client.channels.fetch('744582158324072468')
        .then (channel => console.log(channel.name))
        .catch(console.error);
       // message.react(args[1]).then(() => message.react(args[0]));
    },
};
```

I already tried to put it in the Main.js which works:

```
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.startsWith('.poll')) {
        client.channels.fetch('744582158324072468')
        .then (channel => console.log(channel.name))
        .catch(console.error); 
    }
}
```

But I want it ion the correct file. This is what I have above the client.on('message', etc.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token, tprefix, welcomechannel, guildID } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client({
    fetchAllMembers: true,
});

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

// update

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${tprefix}Paperbot got geupdated.`);
});
```

Of course, I googled around and read the documentation but that didn't help.

As I said, I am new to programming and it could be an easy fix, but I would love to fix this problem as fast as possible, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I just needed to add message to `client.channels.fetch`

Now it is working with this code:

```
const { tprefix, pollchannel, modchannel } = require('../config.json');


 module.exports = {
    name: 'poll',
    description: 'can make polls',
    cooldown: 5,
    usage: '[ask] [emoji1] [emoji 2]',
    aliases: ['createpoll'],
    execute(message) {
        message.client.channels.fetch('744582158324072468')
        .then (channel => console.log(channel.name))
        .catch(console.error);
    },
};
```

Thank you @Jack Towns

Comment: If somebody's answer solved your problem, please [mark it as accepted](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers&ved=2ahUKEwiFze3xsKDrAhUE01kKHa6iCkAQFjABegQIDxAF&usg=AOvVaw3j9ZZbNDJSWa0_RnySATof)

Answer (score 1):

You assign client to a new Discord collection at the top of your code.

You are essentially doing `Collection.channels.fetch` instead of `client.channels.fetch`.

You need to pass the client from your main file to your commands.

Comment: Now I am getting this:
`HTTPError [DiscordjsError]: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.`

Comment: @centrix.js that most likely means your token is invalid, try regenerating it on the dev panel.